# How to find column of same values in csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file test.csv. It have 5000 columns. Some of columns (example 50 columns), have same value in all rows. How can I find how many column have same value and print those columns in separate csv.
Example,

```
A B C D
1 2 2 3
1 2 3 3
1 2 4 3
1 2 5 3
1 2 7 3
```

I want to find columns which have similar values/elements such as A,B and D . Then print those A,B and D in separate CSV file and C in separate CSV.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you made any attempts to solve this task?

Comment: to clarify, you need to get an entire column where any of its value is a row duplicate.

Comment: yes, tried with csvreader and for loop to read the column elements, csvr=csv.reader(file) for row in csvr: read , but unable to read all columns with header.

Comment: Hi , I solved by using python pandas nunique method to find the unique columns and  convert the unique column to csv and non-unique columns to another csv.  Thank you for all the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using pandas. You can solve your problem with something like the below (which should get you started).

You'll need to review this link which will give you an overview of [10 minutes to pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) (i.e. reading in/manipulating data)

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'A': [1] * 5
    , 'B': [1] * 5
    , 'C': [1] * 5
    , 'D': [i for i in range(2, 7)]

}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# loop through each column
for col in df.columns.tolist():
    # check if every value in the column is equal to the first value
    if (df[col] == df[col][0]).all():
        print('all values match in {col}'.format(col=col))
    else:
        print('{col} has non-uniform values'.format(col=col))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas for pretty IO. 
Just write a function to test a column and select the good ones :

Input :

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv()
```

A short circuit function,which compare all values only if necessary:

```
from numba import njit
@njit # optional, for efficiency
def equal(arr):
    ref=arr[0]
    for x  in arr[1:]:
        if x != ref : return False
    return True
```

Output:

```
mask=df.apply(equal,axis=0,raw=True)
#[ True, True, False, True ]
df.loc[:,mask].to_csv('equal.csv',sep=' ',index=False)
df.loc[:,~mask].to_csv('notequal.csv',sep=' ',index=False)
```

For:

```
A B D
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

and

```
C
2
3
4
5
7
```

Answer (score 0):

Just find the columns which have only 1 unique value:

Create a `DataFrame`, I'm creating with some dummy data, you can read the csv with [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1], 'B': [2,2,2,2,2,2,2], 'C': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})
>>> df
   A  B  C
0  1  2  1
1  1  2  2
2  1  2  3
3  1  2  4
4  1  2  5
5  1  2  6
6  1  2  7
```

Find those columns which have only 1 unique value:

```
>>> equal_cols = [c for c in df.columns if len(df[c].unique()) == 1]
>>> equal_cols
['A', 'B']
```

Write those columns to `sample1.csv`, and all others to `sample2.csv`.

```
>>> df[equal_cols].to_csv('sample1.csv')
>>> df[c for c in df.columns if c not in equal_cols].to_csv('sample2.csv')
```